# Are there any options for choosing and showing a Primary Category in EE3?

Tags: categories, ee3

I am upgrading a site to EE3. I have a channel with 3 separate category groups, with 2-3 levels of categories in each group. Any particular entry could have 3-6 categories selected.

For breadcrumbs on an entry, I'd like to be able to select a primary category so that I only display on breadcrumb trail for the entry instead of a list of all the associated categories.

Is there a solution for how to do this in EE3. Solspace "Primary Category" is not EE3 compatible and is discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I was going to suggest using standard categories tags and the parent_only parameter, but I don't think that will get you all the way there.

Sounds like you might be able to use GWcode Categories.  This is an EE2 plugin that lets you set categories display and control their depth, etc.

While the plugin is EE2, [there is a beta](http://gwcode.com/gwcode_categories_3beta.zip) that seems to work on EE3 without issue. You can find more info via the [devot:ee support forum](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/gwcode-categories/viewforum/1444)